# Assembly language how to use WriteBinB correctly?

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I'm trying to transform a number '2' presented by '＊' and '　' by constructing an array called `chstrs` like the following code into '0' and '1'.

In other words, I want to change '　' to '0' and '＊' to '1', moving the result to `bitstrs` and print it out.

My problem is that I can't print the right answer even though I successfully transform `chstrs` into `bitstrs`.

Here is `chstrs` and `bitstrs` after whole program

[image]  [image]

After I printed `bitstrs`, it turned out like this.

[image]

But this is what I really want. How can I deal with it?

[image]

Here's my code.

```
TITLE Assembly 

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

main          EQU start@0

.data

    chstrs  BYTE "  ***   "     
            BYTE "**   ** "
            BYTE "**   ** "
            BYTE "    **  "
            BYTE "   **   "
            BYTE "  **    "
            BYTE " **     "
            BYTE "********"
    bitstrs BYTE 8 DUP(?)
.code

transform PROC      ;transform ' ' to 0, '*' to 1
    push ecx
    mov ecx, 8
    mov bl, '*'     
L2:
    mov al, [esi]   ;move chrstrs into al
    cmp al, bl      ;compare al and '*'
    jb L3           ;if a is below '*', al=' '
    add al, 7       
    jmp L4
L3: 
    add al, 16  
    jmp L4
L4: 
    mov [edi], al   ;move al to bitstrs after transforming
    inc edi
    inc esi
    loop L2
    pop ecx
    ret
transform ENDP

main PROC
    mov esi, offset chstrs
    mov edi, offset bitstrs
    mov ecx, 8
    
L1:
    call transform
    mov eax, bitstrs
    call writebinb      ;trying to print bitstrs, but I can't do it right
    call crlf
    loop L1
    

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: `writebinb` takes more than one parameter.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm what do you mean? I am new to ASM language. Do I have to move bitstrs to more parameter and print it out?

Comment: The `writebinb` function takes a value in `ebx` that specifies the size of the number to output. Check your documentation.